# Is there a CLI command to show if packages need to be updated

Tags: apt

When you login, you are shown "X packages can be updated, Y are security updates," Is there a terminal command that will give this message on demand?

Comment: `apt list --upgradeable`

Comment: The login message is called "motd". It's configured in `/etc/motd` and `/etc/update-motd.d`, so you could check there to see what command prints that message. Related: [How to change welcome message (motd) on Ubuntu 18.04 server - LinuxConfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-welcome-message-motd-on-ubuntu-18-04-server)

Comment: @wjandrea thanks, this is 16.04 and it's not where you suggest (neither file exists) any idea where it might be on 16.04?

Comment: @user1130176 Oh, you're right, `/etc/motd` isn't used anymore, but `/etc/update-motd.d` should still exist. You're aware it's a directory, right? See [`man update-motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/update-motd.5.html). Maybe it's in `/etc/pam.d/login` instead? See [`man motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/motd.5.html).